# Removing nodes from a TreeView with multiple selection (TreeViewMS)

Tags: c#, treeview

I need a treeview component with multipleselect. So I downloaded "[C# TreeView with multiple selection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2756/C-TreeView-with-multiple-selection)".  Now I am having trouble removing items.  The following code runs fine, but removes nothing:

```
private void removeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < treeView1.SelectedNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (treeView1.Nodes[i].IsSelected)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes[i].Remove();
                i--;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    } 

        treeView1.Update();
        treeView1.Refresh();
}
```

---

```
treeView1.SelectedNodes.Remove();
```

Requires an object, but I don't know which.

```
foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.SelectedNodes)
            tn.Remove();
```

Throws an exception because the collection was modified.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a backward loop and use the Remove method on the Nodes collection passing the selected node

```
private void removeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    for (int i = treeView1.SelectedNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        TreeNode n = (TreeNode)treeView1.SelectedNodes[i];
        treeView1.Nodes.Remove(n);
    }
    treeView1.Update(); 
    treeView1.Refresh(); 
}
```

Also I don't think you have to test if the node IsSelected because you are already using the SelectedNodes property. (Really I  haven't checked if this is the case with this customized treeview class, however the name suggest that the nodes included are already selected)

Comment: Yes, out of range, my bad. Need to use the SelectedNodes collection. Could you try with my updated answer?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I added (TreeNode) as SelectedItems returns an ArryList, not TreeNodes...